# How to find process by windows title and close it whenever open

Tags: c++

I want to close process by windows title whenever that process open. How i do it?

Comment: WHich os are you running?

Comment: i have a sneaky suspicion that this will be used for malware....

Comment: I'm use this for protect my game client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, use `FindWindow()` to locate a window with the desired title, and if found then use `PostMessage()` to post a `WM_QUIT` message to it.  If the window is still running after a period of time, then you might be able to brute force kill it, depending on permissions, by using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, `OpenProcess()` and `TerminateProcess()`.

Comment: Can you give me full source

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for the functions I mentioned? They are all straight forward to use. I shouldn't need to write the code for you.  If you run into a particular problem, then ask about it. But do try to write some code yourself first.